# context:property-holder Vs. PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: spring

How do I make use of @Value in the following 2 cases?

**case 1:** I have a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean defined as follows

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:#{ systemProperties['user.home']}/myconf/settings.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Case 2:** I did not define the bean, but i have declared property-place holder in the context as follows

```
<context:property-placeholder 
     location="file:#{ systemProperties['user.home']}/myconf/settings.properties"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you would use like

```
@Value(value="${key.in.file}")
private String myVar;
```